# How do i return an object from a function in Delphi without causing Access Violation?

Tags: delphi

I have a delphi function that returns a TStringList, but when I return a value and try to use it I get a Access Violation Error i.e

```
myStringList := FuncStringList();
myStringList.Items.Count   // <-- This causes an access violation

// function FuncStringList
function FuncStringList:TStringList;
var
  vStrList:TStringList;
begin

  vStrList := TStringList.Create;
   ...
  // Fill the vStrList

  Result := vStrList 
  vStrList.Free;    //<- when i free here, this function will cause AccessViolation
end;
```

How can I return the TStringList and still free it in the local function?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As Smasher said, you can't free it; the code calling the function that returns the object is responsible for destroying it.

This is bad code design, by the way, as it makes it confusing as to who allocates and frees. A much better way to do it would be to have the caller create the object and pass it in to the function. That way, the code that creates it also frees it. Something like this:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ProcToFillStringList(SL);
    //Do something with populated list
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;

// Note I've made the parameter a TStrings and not a TStringList. This allows
// passing a TMemo.Lines or a TListBox or TComboBox Items as well.
procedure ProcToFillStringList(const SList: TStrings);
  // Do whatever populates the list with SList.Add()
end;
```

Now there's no confusion over who does what - the same code that creates the object is responsible for freeing it. And the code, IMO, is much clearer to read and maintain.

Comment: Careful.  Since stack-allocated variables aren't initialized to 0, and assigned() only checks for <> nil, failing to create it before calling the function will *not* trigger the assertion.

Answer (score 27):

> How can i return the TStringList and still free it in the local function?

You can't. If you free it in the local function, you can't use the return value. Result and vStrList point to the same TStringList object in memory. TStringList is a class and

```
Result := vStrList
```

does therefore not copy the string list, but only copies the reference.

So, instead you should free the string list in the calling context after you're done working with it or pass the string list as a parameter to your function like this

```
procedure FuncStringList (StringList : TStringList);
```

and let the calling code create and free the string list. As pointed out by the other answers, this is the preferable way, since it makes ownership very clear.

Comment: +1, but you should IMHO add a note that the second way (have the caller pass the string list as reference) is the standard Delphi idiom, and that the first is really only suitable for factory functions and the like.

Comment: You're absolutely right and I edited my answer like you proposed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer: you can't.  Why are you trying to?  Is it because you've learned that you need to free every object you create in the same function in which they're created?  That's generally correct, but not always, and this is one of the exceptions to the rule.  A better way to put it is that every object must be freed by its owner.

If you have a function that generates an object, like this one, but then passes it on to another function, it doesn't take ownership of the object.  Remove the call to free and document it, so you (and anyone else who uses this function) will realize that it creates a new object that the code that calls it has to take ownership of.

Comment: Exactly my view. I give functions like this a name starting with Create, so the caller has a clue that he has to handle the returned object similar to the result of a constructor call.

Answer (score 4):

**Simple answer (with examples):**

When you do

> Result := vStrList

you assign vStrList to Result. At this moment vStrList and Result **ARE THE SAME THING!** So, in the next line of code, when you free vStrList, you free also Result (well, this is not TECHNICALLY accurate but I used it to keep the explanation simple). This is why you get an AV when you try to use the result of the function. The Result was destroyed when you freed vStrList.

So, this will solve your problem:

```
function FuncStringList:TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  // Do stuff with Result
  // never free (here, in this function) the Result
end;
```

The caller of FuncStringList will HAVE TO free "Result".

You call it like this:

```
myStringList := FuncStringList;
try 
  myStringList.Items.Count                      
finally
  FreeAndNil(myStringList);    <------------- NOW you can free "Result"
end;
```

.

**Another example:**

```
function makelist: tstringlist;
begin
  result := Tstringlist.create;
  result.add('1');
  result.add('2');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_GOOD_Click(Sender: TObject);
var list : tstringlist;
begin
  list := makelist;
  DoStuff(list);
  list.free;      //ok
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_BAD_Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  listbox1.items.Assign(makelist);  // <---- memory leak here because you forgot to free
end;
```

---

I put this note here before anyone will start 'picking' on my explanation. I used some 'shortcuts' in my explanation in order to avoid complex concepts (such as pointer assignment) keep things very simple. @gath asked a basic question which means that he is still learning the basics of programming.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot free something and then expect to reference it later. That is the wrong way. You have two basic options:

- Do not call free, and make the caller responsible for disposing of the object
- Have the caller pass in an object so that it's responsible for both Create and Free

The first option seems simpler, keeps the interface to the function smaller, etc. The second option makes usage less error prone because it's intuitive to the caller that it's responsible for managing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't free the object before you are done invoking the methods on it. You are currently invoking the Count method on a destroyed object, hence the error.

Why don't you create the string list in the calling function instead, and pass its reference to the method that fills it? Or make the string list a member of a class, and free it when you free the class that owns it?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a dynamic array instead of a TStringList. Since arrays are reference counted, you will never have to worry about freeing it.

Comment: Not really helpful, as most of the existing code works with TStrings. Or is there a way in recent Delphi versions to assign a dynamic array of strings to a TStrings object? To sort it? It would also be missing the Objects property. There are enough reasons to stay with TStrings.

Comment: Yeah, but instead you have to worry about manually adjusting the length of the array. If you implement this naive enough, you will end up with a very poor performing snippet of code. I really prefer using TStringList.

Comment: Well it really depends what he's doing with it -- I just pointed it out as a possibility. All I see is an ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

A policy I have with such situations is to pass the stringlist content through the text property and just pass the string returned to the function. This way there's no need to discuss who release who. Of course, you have to do a little more coding, but it's safer. 
The example is an adaptation of the Ken White's one :

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  Aux: String;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Text := ProcToFillStringList;
    //Do something with populated list
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;

 // It receives a default param, in the case you have to deal with 
 // StringList with some previous content    
 function ProcToFillStringList(SListContent: String = ''):String;
 // Do the stuff you need to do with the content
end;
```

An exception is when all you have is the object and there's no way to retrieve the content on it through a safe type (in this case, strings); then I follow Ken White's idea.

Answer (score 0):

both are reffering to same memory,if you free it both will get freed.......

Answer (score 0):

Either as Out variable.

```
function GetList(Parameter1: string; out ResultList: TStringList): boolean;
begin
  // either
  if not Assigned(ResultList) then
    raise Exception.Create('Out variable is not declared.');
  // or
  Result := False;
  if not Assigned(ResultList) then
    Exit;
  ResultList.Clear;
  ResultList.Add('Line1');
  ResultList.Add('Line2');
  //...
  Result := True;
end;
```

Or as string.

```
function GetList(Parameter1: string): string;
var
  slList: TStringList;
begin
  slList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    slList.Clear;
    slList.Add('Line1');
    slList.Add('Line2');
    //...
    Result := slList.Text;
  finally
    slList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

.

```
procedure Main;
var
  slList: TStringList;
begin
  slList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // either
    GetList(Parameter1, slList);
    // or
    slList.Text := GetList(Parameter1);
    // process slList...
  finally
    slList.Free;
  end;
end;
```